# Polite way of saying "stop smoking here"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

Which one of the following is correct :
Would you mind "no smoking" here
Would you mind "not smoking" here

Comment: Do you want a choice between just those two options or different alternatives?

Comment: @KillingTime Which one of them is grammatically correct and widely used?

Answer (score 1):

The grammatically correct way to say it is:

```
Would you mind not smoking here?
```

This is one of the situations where *-ing* should be used only. (like after `recommend`).

Comment: Although the answer to that question might be "yes, I would mind". A better way of saying it would be "Please do not smoke here".

Comment: @KillingTime - Only if there is a rule prohibiting it.  If they have every right to smoke but you are asking for them to be considerate, that’s not a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

If people are smoking in a no-smoking area and you are addressing them personally then "Please extinguish your cigarettes" is probably the most polite yet pointed way to say it.

If you are simply looking for wording for a sign then "NO SMOKING" is the way to go.

Comment: Also "Please refrain from smoking"